# Duda Java + MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas tengo una duda con un multi update en java: quiero lanzar varias sentencias update concatenadas en un stringBuilder.

El formato del stringBuilder es el siguiente:

```
"UPDATE morosos SET importe = importe + 80 WHERE dni = '33333333C';UPDATE morosos SET importe = importe + 100 WHERE dni = '44444444D'; etc, etc..."
```

Mi intención es ejecutar todas esas sentencias con un executeUpdate, pero me lanza el siguiente error:

> 'com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax;'

```
public void actualizarMorosos(String path, ConexionRecuperacion con) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            ArrayList<String> dniMorosos = new ArrayList<>();
            ResultSet rs = con.rs("SELECT * FROM morosos");
            while (rs.next()) {
                dniMorosos.add(rs.getString("dni"));
            }

            update = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                /* separacion de las lineas */
                String[] split = line.split("#");
                /* quitamos la primera linea */
                if (!line.contains("RECIBO") || !line.contains("PISO") || !line.contains("IMPORTE")) {
                    if (dniMorosos.contains(split[2])) {
                        update.append("UPDATE morosos SET ");
                        update.append("importe = importe + " + split[5]);
                        update.append(" WHERE dni = '" + split[2] + "';");
                    }
                }
            }

            /* imprimir query */
            System.out.println(update.toString());
            /* lanzar query */
            con.update(update.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: deberia existir un espacio entre el ; y tu siguiente sentencia: ";UPDATE ...."

Comment: ¿Podrías poner la cadena completa obtenida del `StringBuilder` y también la traza de error completa... ¿no dice algo como *`Near at`*  en el mensaje de error?

Comment: prueba dicha sentencia en tu gestor de base de datos mysql

Comment: probablemente no está agregando espacios entre el final de una sentencia y el inicio de la otra. Le sugiero [edit] la pregunta con la múltiples sentencias SQL armadas en el stringBuilder. También *(para efectos de comprensión)*, cambie el título de esta pregunta.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement

Comment: Esta es la cadena del StringBuilder: UPDATE morosos SET importe = importe + 80 WHERE dni = '33333333C'; UPDATE morosos SET importe = importe + 100 WHERE dni = '44444444D'; UPDATE morosos SET importe = importe + 90 WHERE dni = '55555555E'; UPDATE morosos SET importe = importe + 30 WHERE dni = '66666666F'; UPDATE morosos SET importe = importe + 60 WHERE dni = '77777777G'; UPDATE morosos SET importe = importe + 60 WHERE dni = '88888888H'; UPDATE morosos SET importe = importe + 70 WHERE dni = '99999999I'; UPDATE morosos SET importe = importe + 80 WHERE dni = '00000000J';

Comment: y este el error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE morosos SET importe = importe + 100 WHERE dni = '44444444D'; UPDATE moros' at line 1

Comment: Aunque en este caso, por seguridad y por rendimiento, lo correcto sería usar consultas preparadas. Preparas una sola consulta y luego le puedes pasar los parámetros dentro de un bucle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu caso yo usaría consultas preparadas y una actualización por lotes usando transacciones.

Esto aporta seguridad al código (evitando ataques de inyección SQL) y rendimiento, ya que el plan de ejecución es preparado una sola vez. Además control, las actualizaciones se revierten si ocurre algún error (por eso el `rollback` en la parte del `catch`...

El proceso es simple:

1. Creas una sola vez la instrucción SQL, cambiando los futuros valores por marcadores
2. Indicas con `setAutoCommit` que vas a iniciar una transacción por lotes
3. Dentro del `while` cuando se cumplan las condiciones, seteas cada valor y luego agregas al lote.
4. Finalmente, al terminar el recorrido, ejecutas el lote de actualizaciones.
5. Y mediante `commit` indicas que ya se puede ejecutar el lote
6. Cuando se usa transacciones, en el `catch` se llama a `rollback` para que deshaga cualquier cambio operado por la transacción en caso de algún error

Sería algo así:

```
public void actualizarMorosos(String path, ConexionRecuperacion con) {
    try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            ArrayList<String> dniMorosos = new ArrayList<>();
            ResultSet rs = con.rs("SELECT dni FROM morosos");
            while (rs.next()) {
                dniMorosos.add(rs.getString("dni"));
            }


            String sql="UPDATE morosos SET importe = importe + ? WHERE dni = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                /* separacion de las lineas */
                String[] split = line.split("#");
                /* quitamos la primera linea */
                if (!line.contains("RECIBO") || !line.contains("PISO") || !line.contains("IMPORTE")) {
                    if (dniMorosos.contains(split[2])) {
                        stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(split[5]));
                        stmt.setString(2, split[2]);
                        stmt.addBatch(); 
                    }
                }
            }

            stmt.executeBatch(); 
            con.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        con.rollback();
    }
}
```

He asumido que `importe` es un número, si fuera del tipo `long` tendrías que convertir a ese tipo y usar `setLong`.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: muchísimas gracias.

Comment: muy concreta y fiable..!!!

Comment: Es una chorrada casi pero en la primera query es mejor solo traer el campo dni en vez de todos con `SELECT dni FROM morosos`

Comment: @JesusRomero había olvidado poner el código completo, como apagar autocommit, usar el rollback en caso de error, etc. Conviene hacerlo así cuando usamos transacciones. Revisa la respuesta editada.

Comment: No @JDev no es ninguna chorrada. Yo he recomendado más de una vez evitar el uso de `SELECT *`, en mi caso nunca lo uso... No tiene sentido traer todas las columnas cuando sólo vas a usar una o algunas.